# Is current user reachable inside symfony's workflow's events

Tags: php, symfony

I am working with symfony/workflow. I've created a subscriber of the event `workflow.[workflow name].guard`. Security is injected ...

```php
class WorkflowRentSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private Security $security,
    ) { }

    public function onCancellationRequest(Event $event)
    {
        throw new \RuntimeException(json_encode([
            'user' => $this->security->getUser(),
        ]));
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            'workflow.rent_status.guard' => 'onSomeEvent',
        ];
    }
}
```

But whenever code is executed returns null user.

```php
RuntimeException : {"user":null}
```

Comment: What fires workflow.rent_status.guard and are you sure it is fired after the authentication system has a chance to load the user from the session?

Comment: Workflow'a apply methods is called in a service inside a controller that is inside a protected route

Comment: Well.  There goes that theory.  Sometimes there are kernel event listeners that try to access the user before it is available but by the time a controller is involved then the user is there.  Assuming the user is authenticated.  All I can suggest is trying to make sure that nothing else is firing the event.